# How to animate outline and axes objects in mayavi

Tags: python, 3d, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have a surface that is changing shape and size in time. I want to draw an outline around it with an axes that moves with it. I can remove and replace the outline and axes with each update but that's not very satisfying. Is there any way to update the existing `axes` and `outline` objects to detect changes to the underlying surface?

```py
from mayavi import mlab

phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:12j, 0:np.pi:12j]

def make_sphere(r):
    x = r * np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    z = r * np.cos(theta)
    return x, y, z


x,y,z = make_sphere(1)
mesh = mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
outline = mlab.outline(mesh)
axes = mlab.axes(color=(0, 0, 0))


def update(t):
    x,y,z = make_sphere(np.abs(np.random.randn(1)))
    mesh.mlab_source.reset(x=x, y=y, z=z)

@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def animate():
    for t in range(1, 1000):
        update(t)
        yield

animate()
mlab.show()
```

[image: too small]
[image: too big]